# Why is the Python 3 Windows AMD64/EM64T/x64 installer a ".amd64" file?

Tags: python-3.x

So I noticed the main download button for Python 3 downloads an executable that runs a wizard that is titled "Python 3 (32 Bit)" so I  figured "ahh that's fine I'll just run 32 bit Python on my 64 bit OS" but out of curiosity I stopped the install and went back to the site to find "Windows x86-64 executable installer  Windows for AMD64/EM64T/x64 4c9fd65b437ad393532e57f15ce832bc    26260496" and it downloads as "python-3.7.1-amd64.exe"I was just wondering what the heck is going on?

Why is the Python 3 Windows AMD64/EM64T/x64 installer a ".amd64" file?

Answer (score 3):

".amd64" is a file extension for 64 bit binaries. While ".exe" is more common, the Python 3 64-bit installer is probably labeled ".amd64" to specify that it is meant to be run on 64-bit machines.

Comment: Thank you, like I said "just wondering," so thank you. I'm sure there's a history behind it, but its awesome that amd has had an impact that deep on systems today, if there is in fact a correlation. Thank you.